# How to create two columns from single one in Pandas dataframe, so that we have pairs in lines?

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column with elements of type string. I need to get 2 columns for future pairwise comparison.

***Example:***
We had:
Abc
Bdf
Ftp
...

What I need to get: (2 different columns)
Abc, Bdf
Abc, Ftp
Bdf, Ftp
...

I've searched a lot of different sources and what I came to is that I need to use itertools. But how?

Comment: Can you provide a dataframe constructor at input?

Answer (score 0):

use `shift`

The dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1'], data = ['Abc','Bdf', 'Ftp'])
```

and the answer

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].shift()
df.fillna(method = 'ffill', axis=1)
```

output:

```
    col1    col2
0   Abc     Abc
1   Bdf     Abc
2   Ftp     Bdf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import combinations

df2 = pd.DataFrame(combinations(df['col1'], 2),
                   columns=('col1', 'col2'))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0  Abc  Bdf
1  Abc  Ftp
2  Bdf  Ftp
```